# protect all pages does not work in asp.net identity for webforms

Tags: webforms, asp.net-identity, password-protection

I have created a new web application using web forms and individual account, I can create a user and login. But I need all pages to be password protected. What do I need to add in order for that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't added a lot of details, but I think the solution for you would be to check if the user is authenticated at Page_Load.

This should be included in your **base** Page class (assuming you have one and your not directly implementing the Page class).

```
 public abstract class MyBaseAuthProtectedPage : Page
 {
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                 //not authenticated logic here
            }
        }
     }
....
 }
```

All your pages should implement the **MyBaseAuthProtectedPage** class.